# Typescript hybrid type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am currently writing a *d.ts files for a private JavaScript file that I cannot modify. I'm currently trying to define a property in an interface that can be either a **string** or a **function**:

```
var obj = {
    href: function(data) { return "/page/" + data.id; }
}
```

OR

```
var obj = {
    href: "page/list.html"
}
```

After looking at the [typescript doc](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook) about interfaces I came across the [follow example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-hybrid-types) but it won't let me define the function as an optional type as shown below:

```
interface IObj {
    href: {
        (...any)?: any;
        string? ;
    };
}
```

Is this even possible? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are really looking for is a `Union` Type (denoted by `|`). For your case:

```
interface IObj {
    href: string | { (...any): any };
};


var obj: IObj = {
    href: "page/list.html"
}

var obj: IObj = {
    href: function (data) { return "/page/" + data.id; }
}

// ERROR
var obj: IObj = { 
    href: 123
}
```

[See an example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20IObj%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20href%3A%20string%20%7C%20%7B%20(...any)%3A%20any%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Avar%20obj%3A%20IObj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20href%3A%20%22page%2Flist.html%22%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20obj%3A%20IObj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20href%3A%20function%20(data)%20%7B%20return%20%22%2Fpage%2F%22%20%2B%20data.id%3B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20ERROR%0Avar%20obj%3A%20IObj%20%3D%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20href%3A%20123%0A%7D)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please note for anyone else that after reading around I found out that Unions are not in version of Typescript below 1.4.